# Python 2.7 IOError: [Errno] No such file or directory: 'GBPUSD1d.txt'

Tags: file, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, directory

I have Python 2.7 Win 32 and have installed Matplotlib, Numpy, PyParsing, Dateutil. In IDLE I place in the following code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np


ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((40,40), (0,0), rowspan=40, colspan=40)

def graphRawFX () :
    global ax1

    date=mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    bid, ask = np.loadtxt('GPBUSD1d.txt', unpack=True)
    delimiter=',',
    converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') }
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))

    ax1.plot(date,bid)
    ax1.plot(date,ask)

graphRawFX()

ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I proceed to run the code with this error coming up:

```
>>> 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Emanuel/Desktop/graphing.py", line 22, in <module>
    graphRawFX()
  File "C:/Users/Emanuel/Desktop/graphing.py", line 14, in graphRawFX
    bid, ask = np.loadtxt('GPBUSD1d.txt', unpack=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 734, in loadtxt
    fh = iter(open(fname, 'U'))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'GPBUSD1d.txt'
>>>
```

Very peculiar as I have the file GPBUSD1d.txt place on my desktop. It used to be in a .zip folder but I took it out as I know python cannot find it if zipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the absolute path to the  GPBUSD1d.txt file. It may be trying to find the file from within the directory python is running from.

Comment: @BenthePyro
So `'C:\Users\Emanuel\Desktop\GPBUSD1d.txt'`
The absolute path is just the path from your root directory to that file. :)

Comment: generally the \ is used as an escape character, doubling them should escape the escape and be correct, is the code working? or is it spitting out an error about them being doubled up?

Comment: ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 20130501000000,1.55358,1.55371 : that's all there is to it the administrator has nothing to do with it, it runs the same but thanks for trying.

Comment: hmmm, what is inside the text file?

Comment: 20130501000000,1.55358,1.55371
20130501000000,1.55357,1.55369
20130501000000,1.55353,1.55367
20130501000000,1.55349,1.55367
20130501000000,1.55349,1.55367
20130501000001,1.55348,1.55367
20130501000001,1.55348,1.55366
20130501000001,1.55347,1.55362
20130501000001,1.55344,1.55363
20130501000002,1.55348,1.55364
20130501000002,1.55348,1.55364
20130501000004,1.55348,1.55363
20130501000006,1.55348,1.55363
20130501000007,1.55344,1.55362
20130501000008,1.55344,1.55362

Represents time and bid price which later will be subracted by percent change

Comment: well the good news is you are now reading the text file correctly. The bad news is, I'm not sure how to correct the float literal part. I'll think on it and come back here if I come up with an answer.